# Need to replace doorbell chime. How to test for voltage without old chime

Tags: wiring, doorbell

I had an old nutone doorbell chime. Previous owners smoked and it was nasty so I threw it away. I should have looked at it to see what replacement chime to buy. So now I have two red wires, and 2 copper wires (copper wires twisted together). My question is, how do I test the voltage to see what doorbell chime I should buy?

Comment: A multimeter is the safest, might need someone to ring the door bell, or find the transformer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Go find the doorbell transformer and **read what it says.**

Or buy a multimeter and check the AC voltage reading between the wires with the doorbell button actuated. But if you know it worked before you threw the chime away, reading the voltage from the data on the transformer should suffice.

(You can also measure from one of the red wires to the junction of the "copper" ones without pushing the button.)

Comment: I am suspecting the transformer is mounted on the stud inside the wall. I don't see one anywhere else. Measuring from one red wire to the copper junction reads less than 1 volt. Sounds like I should measure voltage from red wire to red wire with the button pushed.

Comment: Did you check each red wire to the copper junction? One should be nothing, one should be live. Were you set on AC volts? Measuring AC while set on DC can give peculiar results. But red to red with the button pushed should work.